# MySQL delete with where not in error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
create table person (
  id integer,
  Email varchar(100)
);


insert into person values (1, 'john@example.com');
insert into person values (2, 'bob@example.com');
insert into person values (3, 'john@example.com');
insert into person values (4, 'john@example.com');
```

Now , I need delete duplicate lines keep the min Id which means after delete the table will be:

```
+----+------------------+
| Id | Email            |
+----+------------------+
| 1  | john@example.com |
| 2  | bob@example.com  |
+----+------------------+
```

I got this to get a list non-duplicate id:

```
select Id from Person group by Email;
```

And delete code is:

```
delete from Person
  where Person.Id not in 
    (select Id from Person group by Email);
```

But not works for me, why I cannot write like this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will delete all duplicated rows, and keep the one with the lowest ID:

```
DELETE p1.*
FROM
  person p1 INNER JOIN person p2
  ON p1.Email=p2.Email
     AND p1.id>p2.id
```

Please see it working [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e902/1).

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it with JOIN as

```
delete p from person p 
join ( 
  select min(id) as id ,email from person group by email 
)p1 
on p1.id < p.id and p1.Email = p.Email ;
```

Comment: But I don't know why I have to add `min(id) as id` , not just `id`, could you tell me, please?

Comment: I am just adding an alias for that called `id` so that I can use it in the join part in more meaningful way. Now The logic is I am getting the min-id for group by email so that I can keep them after the delete.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will give you what you are looking for:

```
delete from Person
  where Person.Id not in 
    (select MIN(Id) from Person group by Email);
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Russ.

First you should go edit>preferences>sql editor and uncheck the safe update box. Then select the query>reconnect to server. Finally run the following query.

```
delete from Person
  where Person.Id not in 
 (select id from (select MIN(Id) as id from person group by email) as p)
```